# heap corruption error when calling SysFreeString()

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

// --------------------------- C# Code ------------------------------

```
    [DllImport("MarshallStringsWin32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    extern static void PassStringOut([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] out String str);

    [DllImport("MarshallStringsWin32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    extern static void FreeString([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] String str);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String str;
        PassStringOut(out str);
        FreeString(str);
    }
```

// --------------------------- C+ Code ------------------------------

```
void PassStringOut(__out BSTR* str)
{
   const std::string stdStr = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
   _bstr_t bstrStr = stdStr.c_str();
   *str = bstrStr.copy();
}

void FreeString(BSTR str)
{
   SysFreeString(str);
}
```

The value of 'str' pointer in PassStringOut() and FreeString() are different, and I am getting a heap corruption error when calling SysFreeString().  Should I pass 'str' by reference to FreeString()?  If so, what is the syntax I should use in C# and C++?

Answer (score 6):

The marshaling layer will allocate a *copy* of the string in managed memory. That copy will be freed by the garbage collector. You do not have to `SysFreeString` a `String` in C#, and in fact, attempting to do so is a great way to corrupt the heap, as you have discovered.

> should I take it that there will be 2 copies performed on the string? The `*str = bstrStr.copy();` and then by the marshalling layer?

Let me describe in more detail what is happening here.

Your `Main` method invokes the unmanaged code, passing the managed address of a local variable of type `String`. The marshaling layer creates its own storage of suitable size to hold a `BSTR` and passes a reference to that storage to your unmanaged code.

The unmanaged code allocates a `string` object that refers to the storage associated with the literal, then allocates a `BSTR` and makes the first copy of the original string into the heap-allocated `BSTR`. Then it makes a second copy of that `BSTR` and fills in the out parameter with a reference to that storage. The `bstrStr` object goes out of scope and its destructor frees the original `BSTR`.

The marshaling layer then makes a managed string of the appropriate size, copying the string for a third time. It then frees the `BSTR` that was passed to it. Control returns to your C# code, which now has a managed string.

That string is passed to `FreeString`. The marshaling layer allocates a `BSTR` and for the fourth time makes a copy of the string into the `BSTR`, which is passed to your unmanaged code. It then frees a `BSTR` which it does not own and returns. The marshaling layer frees the `BSTR` that it allocated, corrupting the heap.

The managed heap remains uncorrupted; the managed string will be freed by the garbage collector at a time of the garbage collector's choosing.

> Should I pass 'str' by reference to FreeString()?

No. Rather, you should stop writing interop code until you have a *thorough* and *deep* understanding of how all aspects of marshalling work.

Marshalling data between managed and unmanaged code is difficult even for experts to get correct. My advice is that you take a large step back and obtain the services of an expert who can teach you how to write interop code safely and correctly, should you need to do so.

Comment: So should I take it that there will be 2 copies performed on the string?  The "*str = bstrStr.copy();" and then by the marshalling layer?

Comment: @Stephenosella: There will be four copies made of the original string; three of those copies are into `BSTR`s and one is into a managed `String`. The last copy is double-freed, corrupting the heap. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work the way you think it works.  The pinvoke marshaller already released the BSTR automatically.  It happened when you called PassStringOut(), the marshaller converted it to a System.String and released the BSTR.  This is the normal and necessary protocol for passing BSTRs between native and managed code.

What goes wrong in FreeString() is that a *new* BSTR got allocated by the pinvoke marshaller.  And it got released **twice**.  First by your native code, again by the pinvoke marshaller.  Kaboom from the debug heap that is used when you run your code with a debugger attached.

You are just helping too much, don't call FreeString().

---

You can get the pinvoke marshaller to handle ANSI strings for you, it is in fact the default behavior since they are so common in legacy C code.  Your C++ function could look like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
void __stdcall PassStringOut(char* buffer, size_t bufferLen)
{
   const std::string stdStr = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
   strcpy_s(buffer, bufferLen, stdStr.c_str());
}
```

With matching C# code:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var buffer = new StringBuilder(666);
        PassStringOut(buffer, buffer.Capacity);
        Console.WriteLine(buffer.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    [DllImport("Example.dll")]
    private static extern bool PassStringOut(StringBuilder buffer, int capacity);
}
```

Having to guess the proper size of the buffer is however the fugly detail.

Comment: OK.  I understand.  Ultimately, what I need is to go from std::string in C++ to System.String in C#.  I do not know the size of the required std::string a priori.  I have posted on this previously.  Using BSTR as the medium seemed the most elegant, although it required the construction of a _bstr_t , which I did not particularly like due to the overhead.  For what I am trying to use, what is the best approach?

Comment: Nothing wrong with BSTR, the pinvoke marshaller likes it a lot.  Nothing wrong with _bstr_t either, it at least helps you to get that std::string converted to Unicode.  If you don't want to use it then you'll need MultiByteToWideChar() to go to Unicode and SysAllocString() to get a BSTR.  Same thing _bstr_t does.  There's always overhead here due to the conversion, std::string is just the previous century's string type.  If you want to cut out the BSTR middle man then pass an initialized StringBuilder that you immediately pass to MultiByteToWideChar(), your function must take a wchar_t*.

Comment: In reality, the back-end code to which I am interfacing (in C++) is strictly ANSI.  Therefore, the std::string that I will be getting from the back-end code (which I simulated) will be ANSI.  Therefore, there really isn't the requirement that I get the string to Unicode other than that is how strings are represented in C#.  Given this, is using BSTR and _bstr_t still the best approach?

Comment: I posted an alternative.

Comment: Your alternative will not work for my use case because I do not know a priori the required buffer size.  If I use "UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr" as the "MarshalAs" parameter, what would the function prototype look like in C++?  Would it also be "out BSTR* str" ?  And if the C# is expecting an ANSI string, I should not have to call MultiByteToWideChar() or use _bstr_t, correct?  Could I just assign the *str to a "char *" string buffer such as std::string . c_str() ?

Is here any good documentation of this topic?  That is given a MarshalAs type what is the corresponding C++ parameter?

Comment: If you can't guess a size up front then you do need to copy the string twice.  Just stick with BSTR then.